# Hydrate an object (OOP PHP), What does it mean?

Tags: php, oop

Everything is in the title. i'm débutant in OOP(PHP), I thank you in advance.

I'm stuck on this since yesterday.

Comment: See [this reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/2x5sur/what_is_hydration/coxmv29/) to the same question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hydrate an object means to 'fill' an object with some data.

Example:

You have a class, let's say, called 'dog'.

```
    class dog{
    public $name;
    public $gender;
}

$hau = new dog();
```

Hydrating would be:

```
$hau->name = 'Hau Hau'
```